# HTML PHP: POST not working correctly

Tags: php, html, raspberry-pi

UPDATE: I have fixed the name issues however it is still not working...using `echo "Hello world"`; to check if the script is running but doesn't show

I created a PHP and HTML script together for testing, works perfectly, now I'm separating the PHP and HTML using `<form action="button.php" method="POST">` however it is not working (The PHP Script is supposed to run a python script that will light up a LCD on a Raspberry pi).

```
 <div>
   <form action="button.php" method="POST">
    <div class="page-header">
             <h1>Buttons</h1>
    </div>
     <p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default" name="Blink">LED Blink</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" name = "LEDOFF">LED OFF</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" name = "LEDON">LED ON</button>

    </p>
    </form>
    </div>
```

PHP SCRIPT:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['Blink']))
{
echo "Hello world";
exec('sudo python /var/www/blink.py');
}
if (isset($_POST['LEDON']))
{
exec('sudo python blink.py');
}
if (isset($_POST['LEDOFF']))
{
exec('sudo python /var/www/blink.py');
}
?>
```

I have configured the Raspberry pi to show PHP errors, however none is shown so it it's somewhere I'm doing wrong in the HTML

Comment: it's not `button name` it's only name. try that and also type is submit and repetition is occuring. without submit type form will not submit

Comment: you're repeating `button`. plus that should be a submit type

Comment: hehehe ^ ;-) no problemo

Comment: you can delete the question if you wish. seems it's been solved in comments ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change button type to submit otherwise the form is never submitted

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div>
       <form action="button.php" method="POST">
        <div class="page-header">
                 <h1>Buttons</h1>
        </div>
         <p>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-default" name="Blink">LED Blink</button>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" name = "LEDOFF">LED OFF</button>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" name = "LEDON">LED ON</button>

        </p>
        </form>       
    </div>
```

Your buttons needs to be input-types.